# How to create insert Markdown content into a popup from a Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I've created a dashboard using Python and Pandas running in a Jupyter Notebook. I wrote a user guide for my dashboard using Markdown. I then created a button labeled "Help". When a user presses the button I want a popup to appear, load my Markdown file from disk, and display the contents of my user guide. The popup should have a scroll bar and a way for the user to close the popup when they are done with it.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?  Sample code would be greatly appreciated.